# how to change focus inside an input

Tags: javascript

The scenario is I need to change the focus of an input when the user press enter.
the input type is date. for instance when the focus is on "day" and user press enter the focus should change to month(exactly like when you press tab).

maybe this snip can help to clear the issue:

[image]

first I have tried to get the next element by querySelectorAll but the next element is the next input not next digit in the input.

```js
function focusNextElement() {
    //add all elements we want to include in our selection
    var focussableElements =
      'a:not([disabled]), button:not([disabled]), input:not([disabled]), [tabindex]:not([disabled]):not([tabindex="-1"])';
    if (document.activeElement && document.activeElement.form) {
        var focussable = Array.prototype.filter.call(
            document.activeElement.form.querySelectorAll(focussableElements),
            function(element) {
                //check for visibility while always include the current activeElement
                return (
                    element.offsetWidth > 0 ||
                    element.offsetHeight > 0 ||
                    element === document.activeElement
                );
            }
        );
        var index = focussable.indexOf(document.activeElement);
        if (index > -1) {
            var nextElement = focussable[index + 1] || focussable[0];
            nextElement.focus();
        }
    }
}
```

any idea?

Comment: share codes please.

Comment: Can you share more details? What's the problem with the given code?

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, this is a semplicistic example but gives you an idea of how to select text on input. Function `createSelection` does the magic. Passing `input reference`, `start` and `end` positions you want to select, by pressing enter, month will be selected.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h3>Focus on input then click Enter</h3>

<input type="text" id="myText" value="07/05/2020">

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var input = document.getElementById("myText");
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
   event.preventDefault();
   createSelection(input, 3, 5);
  }
});

function createSelection(field, start, end) {
    if( field.createTextRange ) {
      var selRange = field.createTextRange();
      selRange.collapse(true);
      selRange.moveStart('character', start);
      selRange.moveEnd('character', end);
      selRange.select();
      field.focus();
    } else if( field.setSelectionRange ) {
      field.focus();
      field.setSelectionRange(start, end);
    } else if( typeof field.selectionStart != 'undefined' ) {
      field.selectionStart = start;
      field.selectionEnd = end;
      field.focus();
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: the problem is : The input element's type ('date') does not support selection.

Comment: Ciao, as you said, input type date does not support selection. If you want to select month by clicking enter, according to what I know, the only workaround you have is to set input type to text.